# Unhandled exception from boost::log when target path file begins with dot ('.')

Tags: c++, path, unhandled-exception, boost-log

I have some troubles with boost::log, when target path begins with dot ('.'). Here's my code (simplicated, but compiled):

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>

void SetupLog()
{
    static bool alreadyInitialized = false;
    if( alreadyInitialized )
        return;

    alreadyInitialized = true;

    auto sink = boost::log::add_file_log(
        boost::log::keywords::target = ".log",
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = "sample_%2N.log"
        );

    boost::log::add_common_attributes();
}

typedef ::boost::log::sources::logger Logger;

class Engine {
public:
    Engine() {
        SetupLog();
        BOOST_LOG( logger ) << "Engine initialized";
    }

private:
    Logger logger;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Engine engine;

    return 0;
}
```

If I call SetupLog before create instance of Engine (and before create logger), then it's will work correct. Also log will be corrected created if I change target to "_log" (without dot at begin), or even if I omit line with target at all and include path to keywords::file_name:

```
auto sink = boost::log::add_file_log(
    boost::log::keywords::file_name = ".log/sample_%2N.log"
    );
```

But when I try to run first variant, then:

1) if directory ".log" don't exist or it's empty, then that folder will be created, but log will saved to worked directory, but not in that path (there aren't any unhandled exception);

2) if that directory already contains some logs, then I have strange exception after run program:

```
    msvcp120d.dll!6ff0732b()    Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for msvcp120d.dll] 
>   JustSandbox.exe!`anonymous namespace'::convert_aux(const wchar_t * from, const wchar_t * from_end, char * to, char * to_end, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & target, const std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> & cvt) Line 111    C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(const wchar_t * from, const wchar_t * from_end, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & to, const std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> & cvt) Line 197 C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::filesystem::path::string(const std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> & cvt) Line 373    C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::filesystem::path::string() Line 367  C++
    JustSandbox.exe!`anonymous namespace'::make_permissions(const boost::filesystem::path & p, unsigned long attr) Line 514 C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::filesystem::detail::status(const boost::filesystem::path & p, boost::system::error_code * ec) Line 1677  C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::filesystem::status(const boost::filesystem::path & p, boost::system::error_code & ec) Line 282   C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(const boost::filesystem::path & p, boost::system::error_code * ec) Line 920   C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::filesystem::create_directories(const boost::filesystem::path & p) Line 399   C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::`anonymous namespace'::file_collector::store_file(const boost::filesystem::path & src_path) Line 666 C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend::rotate_file() Line 1262   C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend::~text_file_backend() Line 1083    C++
    [External Code] 
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend>::destroy() Line 65   C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend * __formal) Line 88 C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pd<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend *,boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend> >::dispose() Line 154   C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() Line 103  C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() Line 375   C++
    [External Code] 
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend> >::destroy() Line 61 C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend> >::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend> * __formal) Line 88  C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pd<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend> *,boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend> > >::dispose() Line 154    C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() Line 103  C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() Line 375   C++
    [External Code] 
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::~core() Line 415  C++
    [External Code] 
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::checked_delete<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core>(boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core * x) Line 34   C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core>::dispose() Line 78   C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() Line 103  C++
    JustSandbox.exe!boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() Line 375   C++
    [External Code]
```

Any ideas what's wrong with this code?

PS: I use boost 1.54.0 with Visual Studio Express 2013 Preview for Windows Desktop.

Edit: I think what this may be just some bug, but before submit it to tracker decided to find, maybe something wrong with my code and I'm didn't know something important (I'm just pretty newby with boost).

Answer (score 2):

Wow. I have the exact same error and stack-trace on exit. I thought it was a bug in my code. (Using visual studio 2013 and boost 1_55_0)

Simply changing the "." in the target name to to some other character makes it works. Thanks for the tip.

As in:

```
//This does not work:
sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(
    keywords::target = "/log/%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S_dbg.log",
...
));

//This works:
sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(
    keywords::target = "/log/%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S_dbg_log",
...
));
```

You should probably make that bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/why_crash_on_term.html) reference in the documentation that it is a workaround.

What it worked for me was:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ...

    logging::core::get()->remove_all_sinks();

    return 0;
}
```